# Format WPF Listview Column to show 2 only decimal points.

Tags: wpf, listview, formatting

How can I format a WPF Listview Column to show 2 only decimal points?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a GridViewColumn within a ListView: if you are using .net3.5 SP1 you can use the StringFormat property of your column's Binding;

e.g.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyData}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Price, StringFormat=Now only {0:#.00}!}"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If you're not on SP1 yet, then a Converter would be the way forward...

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/29/trying-out-binding-stringformat.aspx) (Link no longer works)

The simplest way is:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:00.00}}" />
```

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Also, the formatting of your code is not correct-- the "`" should be removed